# Отображение карты google в админке wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps-api

Попытался реализовать отображение карты google на одной из страничек админки вордпресса, но к сожалению так ничего и не получилось, сам код по инициализации вроде как отрабатывает, но на месте карты видно только прямоугольник , то есть самой карты нету.
Код который использую для добавления карты в админку:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','admin_map_function');
function admin_map_function(){
    wp_enqueue_script('google_map','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js','jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('init',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/map_.js','google_map','',true);
}
```

**map_.js**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).load()
    {
        var lat = $('#latitude').value;
        var long = $('#longtitude').value;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom:17,
            scrollwheel:false,
            center:myLatlng,
            disableAutoPan:true
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-contact'), mapOptions);
    }
})
```

при формировании самой странички в месте расположения карты вывожу:

```
echo '<div id="map-canvas-contact"></div>
```

В результате ошибок в консоли браузера нету, но и карта тоже не отображается, только прямоугольник

Answer (score 2):

Вы уверены, что используете тот метод jQuery, который вам необходим? Почему load()? Что вы хотите загрузить? Может, имеется в виду что-то вроде: https://jsfiddle.net/q7qtvdvy/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var lat = $('#latitude').value;
    var long = $('#longtitude').value;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: myLatlng,
        disableAutoPan: true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-contact'), mapOptions);
});
```

Comment: Да, Вы правы, там немного не тот метод, jQuery(document).ready это то что нужно написать, только при этом все равно карта не отображается, а только лишь прямоугольник на том месте где должна быть карта

Comment: Разбирайтесь дальше: выводите в консоль переменные `lat` и `long`. Им присваиваются корректные значения?

Comment: да, они корректно считывают значения с полей ввода, сам код отрабатывает, так как если смотреть через тот же firebug, то внутри div'а с ид "map-canvas-contact" появляються другие элементы

Comment: тогда в чём именно проблема? Может, карта у вас всё-таки отрисовывается, но из-за большого значения `zoom` вы видите ничем не размеченную область? Попробуйте установить `zoom:5`

Comment: нет, карта не прорисовывается, прокрутка не работает, хотя например курсор меняет свою форму как положено при наведении на участок где должна располагаться карта, нету дополнительных элементов карты ( тех же кнопок масштаба, переключения режима карт)  этот же код инициализации используется во фронтэнде и там карта отображается корректно, я никак не могу понять что ей мешает в админке вордпреса

Comment: тогда, возможно, вам поможет ответ из этого [вопроса](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964849/how-to-resolve-google-maps-javascript-conflict-with-wordpress-admin-javascript)

Comment: Увы, это немного не мой случай, никаких проблем с совместимостью скриптов не вижу, ошибок в консоли браузера нету, проблем с другими элементами управления в админке тоже не нахожу